# How we can display two ng-repeat alternately one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, gridview, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two ng-repeat  i want to display them in the grid one by one alternately from both of the tr's. Like first index of first tr then first index of 2nd tr. If any help really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Hello, you'll get a few comments like this. - Edit your post and paste your code so we can work with something. - Since this is your first it'll feel bumpy but the more you can get us the better the results. People fly through these if they don't have enough info they are off to the next question. Welcome to Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to weave your two arrays together.  Something like this:

```
 function combine(arr1, arr2){
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++){
      result.push(arr1[i]);
      result.push(arr2[i]);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

(this is a simple example, and doesn't account for the arrays being different sizes.)

Then you can assign a `$scope` variable to the result of this function, and use that variable in the `ng-repeat`.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BtVHNiwJWI4X7sCb95Z6?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Jerrad that the thing i want i implemented it and it works. Thanks again....

Answer (score 0):

Create in the scope an array containing the stuff from your 2 initial arrays and then you'll be able to ng-repeat the big array containing all your elements in the right order.